# Can random forests use cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

As cross validation may help limit overfitting, I think this tech can also help random forest to avoid overfitting sometime. But it is little weird using cross validation because random forests are already an ensemble method using random samples when training.

Comment: what is your goal with using cross-validation?

Comment: @charles As cross validation may help limit overfitting, I think this tech can also help random forest to avoid overfitting sometime.